# DOS FOR loop - Can I use an entire word as a delimiter (multi-character-delimiter)

Tags: loops, for-loop, dos, delimiter

I have a source file that would look something like this:

```
Name                SerialNumber          
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  000000002027612  
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  000000002027476 
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  00000000202746E  
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3  00000000202760E
```

Using FOR loops in dos I need to be able to parse out just the number associated with each PHYSICALDRIVE entry to be used later in the bat file. eg: 1,0,2 and 3)

From what I gather the delims= only looks at one character at a time.
Since I can't say  delims=**PHYSICALDRIVE** and have it treat that as a single delimiter.
Can anyone give an example on how to parse out only the numbers at the end of the string?

In case it matters Delayed expansion is being used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think any solution will require first parsing out the full column value, and then using SET search and replace or substring to parse out the number at the end.

I'm assuming the Name column value can never have a space within it. So the default FOR /F delimiters will parse out the 1st column easily enough.

If the drive number will always be less than 10 then

```
for /f %%A in (yourFileName.txt) do (
  set "drive=%%A"
  set "drive=!drive:~-1!"
  echo !drive!
)
```

Else if it can be 10 or greater then

```
for /f %%A in (yourFileName.txt) do (
  set "drive=%%~A"
  set "drive=!drive:*physicaldrive=!"
  echo !drive!
)
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. I went with the 10 or greater option for future flexibility.