# remove string from filenames with .bat batch file

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have a folder with thousands of filenames like this. I need to put them inside folders and remove the useless parts from the filenames. I need to do this before adding the files inside my XBMC library.

```
[ www.AnnoyingSpam.com ] Some.File.Name.With.A.Very.Long.String.avi
[ www.AnnoyingSpam.com ] Another.File.With.A.Very.Long.String.mpg
[ www.AnnoyingSpam.com ] Again.And.Again.mp4
```

- First, I want to strip the AnnoyingSpam.com tags in the files
- Then, create a folder based on the file name without the tag and without the extension
- Finally, move the file to the new folder
- Repeat for the rest of the files in the root directory of the batch file

So far all I got is a script that will create folder and move files. But it adds the tag "Folder" to each folder and it doesn't remove the AnnoyingSpam.com tag

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims=?" %%a in (`dir /a-d /b`) do (
  if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"
)

goto :EOF

:func
set file=%~1
set dir=%file% Folder
md "%dir%" Folder 2>nul
move "%file%" "%dir%" 
goto :EOF
```

So my question is how can i remove these strings from the folder names that are being created in the above script:

"[ www.AnnoyingSpam.com ]"

" Folder"

Comment: As far as I know batch files (on Windows) are rather limited in their functionality. Would [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) be acceptable here?

Comment: Note that if this is a one-off, and the prefix is the same for each file, then you can just browse to the folder in Windows Explorer, Ctrl+A to select all the files, F2 to edit them, remove the prefix from the one it lets you edit, and press Enter. It's smart enough to remove the same part from all the selected files, preserving the rest of the filenames.

Comment: insert `echo %file:*] =%` after the `set file=%~1` line. The rest should be easy.

Comment: Even though your question has now been reopened (presumably thanks to being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307383)), I think it may still be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, as you're basically asking for someone to write a script for you, rather than asking for help with some specific problem you had while writing one yourself. Since your original problem (batch renaming files) isn't really programming-related anyway, you might want to consider asking about it on [su] instead.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - batch scripting is *on-topic* here. OP has attempted a solution, it's a fairly reasonable question. Bit a shame about the pile on presumably due to the meta question. No wonder OP is pissed off.

Comment: @libertaire - do you have PowerShell available?

Comment: @Kev: The OP has "a script found on google" that they, by their own admission, don't really understand. That's not really an "attempted solution" in the SO sense. And most of the downvote pile-on [happened before the meta post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32857540/timeline), presumably due to the OP's self-vandalism. But yeah, things did get off to a bad start here, and I can understand the OP's annoyance. IMO, the *original* problem was that they posted this in the wrong place; this really is an SU question, not an SO one (and Matthew Strawbridge's comment would make a great answer on SU).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are performing the check `if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"`, my understanding is that you will be running the batch from inside the 'target' folder.

What follows is a `batch` script, based structurally on your sample, that accomplishes the necessary filtering and handles the rename and move operations.

```vb
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "usebackq delims=?" %%a in (`dir /a-d /b`) do (
    if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"
)
endlocal

echo Done.
goto EOF

:func
set file=%~1

for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!file!") do (
    rem stripped extension, next step is to filter to remove the 'spam' part
    set "c=%%~Na"
    rem original filename, will be needed for the renaming
    set "o=%%~a"
    rem store the extension to use later on when re-constructing the filename
    set "e=%%~xa"
    rem this is effectively a multichar stripper; filters the 'spam' part out
    set "c=!c:[ www.AnnoyingSpam.com ] =!"
    rem reconstruct the filename
    set "f=!c!!e!"
    rem echo !o! : !c! : !e! ::: !f!
    rem rename original file to the filtered version
    ren "!o!" "!f!"
    rem create dir named after the filtered filename, if it does not already exist; just a precaution
    if not exist !c! (md !c!)
    rem move the filtered file to the appropriate dir
    move "!f!" "!c!" > nul
)

:EOF
```

---

The script is almost self-explanatory (see the comments inside), however there are some aspects that I would like to point out:

- The instructions `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `endlocal`, that in fact form a wrap around the `for-loop`, establish that the variables inside the loop will be evaluated (expanded) at the execution time and not during parse time. Notice that the variables are referenced inside the loop as `!var!`. See more on this [here](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).
- The removal of the unwanted *'spam'* part is performed by this command: `set "c=!c:[ www.AnnoyingSpam.com ] =!"`. What it does is best described by the following example: `set "var=!var:substring1=substring2!"`, has as a result the substitution of every occurrence of *substring1* by *substring2* in *var*.
  If substring2 is `null` (as is the case here), then the actual effect is the removal of every *substring1* pattern found in the original variable. More on this [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), and for an interesting use as a multichar delimiter see *dbenham's* answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768496/4711309).

And, as always, test thoroughly before you use the script on the actual folders.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've asked for a batch script, but if you have php installed, you can use this:

**renameSpam.php**

```
<?php

$removeTag = "[ www.AnnoyingSpam.com ]";

foreach(glob("*.*") as $file){

    if (strpos($file, $removeTag) !== false) {
        $newFile = trim(str_ireplace($removeTag, "", $file));
        $ext = pathinfo($newFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $fnNoExt = basename($newFile,".".$ext);

        if(!is_dir($fnNoExt)){
            mkdir($fnNoExt, 0777);
            rename($file, "./$fnNoExt/$newFile");
        }else{
            rename($file, "./$fnNoExt/$newFile");
        }

    }
}
```

---

Place `renameSpam.php` on the directory with the files to rename and execute as `php renameSpam.php`.
I've tested this on windows and linux and it works as intended.

Comment: Please do not confuse "batch" and "bash", those are two completely different things...

Comment: I really need a .bat file because the machine doesnt have PHP installed :/

Comment: @libertaire You might consider installing it or perhaps using Python. While I'm sure doing this in a .bat file is possible, I find .bat files difficult to work with and (worse) debug. Those other options will get you further with less work even if you need to come up to speed on the syntax & libraries.

Comment: @FrankV i've created a few .bat files but you don't even need to go that far and install php or phython, libertaire should have powershell .... since its been out since 2008 .... which makes it simpler than installing new languages to deal with what seems to be very uncommon occurance

Comment: @Daemedeor I fully agree with you.